# ListAdapter not updating recyclerView with data from livedata

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore, android-mvvm

i am using firebase firestore with MVVM to download data, i am using a repository layer to fetch and hold data in the application level, a viewModel layer to observe changes and make calls for the repository, and a fragment to show the data. The problem is that, even though i can fetch the data successfully, it is not displayed on the recyclerview.

Repository class:

```
fun fetchAppsFromFirestore() {

    val list = mutableListOf<AppModel>()

    firestore.collection(APPS_COLLECTION).get().addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot ->

        for (doc in querySnapshot) {
            val app = doc.toObject(AppModel::class.java).also {
                it.docId = doc.id
            }
            list.add(app)
        }
        
        //This is a global mutableLiveData
        readingLiveData.value = list

    }
}
```

ViewModel class:

```
fun getData() : LiveData<AppModelReadingResponse> {
    repo.fetchAppsFromFirestore()
    return repo.readingLiveData
}
```

So far the code does what it should do, if i log on the viewModel, all the items on the list are there.

Adapter Class:

```
class FeaturedAppAdapter(val context: Context) :
ListAdapter<AppModel, FeaturedAppAdapter.FeaturedAppViewHolder>(AppModelComparator()) {

class AppModelComparator : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<AppModel>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: AppModel, newItem: AppModel): Boolean {
        return oldItem.docId == newItem.docId
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: AppModel, newItem: AppModel): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }

}


inner class FeaturedAppViewHolder(private val binder: RowFeaturedAppsBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binder.root) {

    fun bind(app: AppModel) {

        binder.rowFeaturedAppsTxtAppName.text = app.appName
        binder.rowFeaturedAppsTxtAppDescription.text = app.appDesc

    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FeaturedAppViewHolder {
    return FeaturedAppViewHolder(
        RowFeaturedAppsBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
    )
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FeaturedAppViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val app = getItem(position)
    holder.bind(app)

}
```

}

And on the fragment that i retrieve the data:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

companion object {
    private const val TAG = "tag_log_info"
}

//Layout components
private val binder by lazy {
    FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
}


//ViewModel
private val appsViewModel: AppsViewModel by viewModels {
    AppsViewModelFactory((requireActivity().application as MyApplication).appsRepository)
}

//RecyclerView
private lateinit var mAdapter: FeaturedAppAdapter

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {

    
    setupRecyclerView()

    return binder.root
}

private fun setupRecyclerView() {

    mAdapter = FeaturedAppAdapter(requireContext())

    with(binder.fragmentHomeRecyclerView){
        this.adapter = mAdapter
        this.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
        this.setHasFixedSize(true)
    }

    observeData()
}

private fun observeData() {

    appsViewModel.getData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        Log.i(TAG, "observeData: $it") // This log shows that the data is here
        mAdapter.submitList(it)
    }

}
```

}

So the problem is that even though the log shows that i have the list of data on the fragment, when i call `submitList(it)`, nothing happens, and i cant figure it out why. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: I think that you might be interested in this article, [How to read data from Cloud Firestore using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953). There are four approaches available, in which one of them is using LiveData. Give it a try and tell me if it wroks.

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks for the article, very useful, but my problem isn't fetching data, with my code i successfully retrieve it. The problem is that i cant update the reyclerView with it. If i log or set some TextView with the data, it works fine, but when i use it on the recyclerView, nothing happens, this is the real problem.

Comment: In that case, try to [listen for real-time updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

Answer (score 0):

In function observeData once the data is set to adapter you have to call `notifyDataSetChanged` function to let adapter know there is change in data.

So your observer function becomes

```
 private fun observeData() {
    appsViewModel.getData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
      Log.i(TAG, "observeData: ${it.list}") // This log shows that the data is here
      mAdapter.submitList(it.list)
      mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
   }
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: I tried this a few times times , it still doesn't work